# Waiting for debugger to disconnect... - Node.js in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to step through a simple javascript example in Visual Studio Code, but the debugger hangs trying to disconnect.

macOS Sierra version 10.12.6

VSCode version 1.18.1 (up to date)

Node.js v8.9.2 (up to date) installed with Homebrew

```
Debugging with inspector protocol because Node.js v8.9.2 was detected.
node --inspect-brk= /*(port)*/ jsSandbox.js 
Debugger listening on ws:// (ip address)
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

This seems like it's been a closed issue with both [Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-node-debug2/issues/11) and [Node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7742) already, which is why I'm so confused. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the only javascript file I'm trying to debug:

```
// learning about closure

function increase() {  // — gets called once
    var getBig = 0;
    return function() {  // — — gets called each time 
        getBig += 1;      // — — increments each time
        console.log(getBig);
    };
}
var bigOne = increase(); // --  a reference to the instance of the function
bigOne(); //1
bigOne();//2
```

...and the project's launch.json config:

```
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/jsSandbox.js",
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
```

Comment: did you installed a different node version using npm, bower? are you using mac/window/ubunto

Comment: updated Node and OS version in post

Comment: Try to force the disconnection with `process.exit()` at the end of your code.

Comment: added `process.exit();` to the end, but it still outputs the same console messages.

Comment: in my case, I had this problem when I have a different node version installed using npm and latest node version installed globally. So can you check node version thru the visual studio code terminal using `node -v`. let me know if it is different or the same?

Comment: it is the same, 8.9.2, good point to check that though.

Comment: In my case, the code was not syntactically valid. After fixing my syntactic errors, the code worked.

Comment: I have the same problem. Was it solved for you?

Comment: Try deleting the launch.json under .vscode folder and retry start debugging. This helped me fix this issue

Answer (score 13):

click on the button as shown below to open launch.json-

[image: To open Launch.json]

Give your correct file name here, where your server is starting. In my case it is app.js

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "runtimeVersion": "10.21.0", 
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"
    }
]
```

runtimeVersion is optional, its required if you want to run it on a specific node version.And that node version should be installed on your system.

Answer (score 12):

I found a syntax error in my code. The problem was that I wasn't catching the exception.
Using VS Code, I just ticked "Uncaught Exceptions" and found the faulty code.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. Helped me figure out that I was providing a path that was getting interpreted incorrectly. Fixed it by adding `${workspaceRoot}`

Comment: Thank you. Good trick. This showed me a path was wrong.

Comment: Where did you tick "Uncaught Exceptions"?

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure the tab showing `problems` is empty, i.e., you should address all problems. In cases where the problems are from the files in `node_modules`, the problems go away just by closing those windows.

For example in the following pictures, there are 4 issues in `Problems` tab. Fixing them will make the debugger to work correctly!

[image]

Comment: Been working with dotnet core lately, and I haven't re-visited this issue. It very well may have been a node module like you say, or id10-T error.

Comment: if the above solution not works, Try deleting the launch.json under .vscode folder and retry start debugging. This helped me fix this issue

Comment: Yeah, having any issues in the Problems tab seems to be one cause. Even minor warnings like **unused variables** caused this for me. Removing unused variables resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

For me a **dependency crashed** while debugging, which seems to also crash the vscode debugger itself. Restarting VSCode would allow me to debug again. Removing the faulty dependency (i.e. fixing the code, as suggested in the other answer), allows the debugging process to close, although the Debug Console message still was confusing:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:48673/54esaf46-659e-sd92-5e45-01e78845825e
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

It would appear the debugger can't disconnect. But I have no trouble starting a new debug session afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Use $'{file}
for active window:

```
{

  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Active window",
    "program": "${file}"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go to settings and make sure debug.javascript is disabled if not make it disabled

Answer (score 0):

Check your launch.json file. Its present in folder .vscode in your project. In launch.json change program value to ${workspaceFolder}/.

Answer (score 0):

For me what helped was the following:

1. created another new debugger anywhere in the program.
2. Run the new debugger
3. Stop the new debugger from the play/stop/step menu

It kind of resets the debugger I think from this "can't disconnect" glitch.

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple "Node Debug" extensions installed. "React Native Tools" had a dependency on both of these. After I removed the "React Native Tools" and then the "Node Debug" extensions, VS Code resumed normal and expected behavior of running the debugger. I used the default launch configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you break your code.
Start your project and you'll see that your app is crashing.
Fix the problem and you'll be able to debug again.

Answer (score 0):

you may check .json
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "启动程序",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/**main.js**"
        }

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me when I added wrong file path in protractor.conf.js specs[]. I forgot to add file extension.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the Task Manager and stopped this process:

```
qemu-system- X86_64.exe (4)
```

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndY81.png)

Answer (score 0):

In package.json, I had the following

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev",
  },
```

Replaced with

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
  },
```

Answer (score -3):

Please check your code firstly, there should be some issues when it compiles your code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, You can post this as comment on question itself instead of answering. [Read: how to answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)